# Totient-function generating sieve consuming too much memory

Tags: haskell, memory, sieve

I have written a sieve-based generator for the list of totients, and want to take the sum up to 1000000.

```
applyEvery :: (a -> a) -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
applyEvery f n xs = xf ++ (\(y:ys) -> f y : applyEvery f n ys) xb
  where
    (xf, xb) = splitAt (n - 1) xs

totients :: [Int]
totients = 1 : sieve [2..] [2..]
  where 
    sieve (x:xs) (y:ys) 
        | x == y    = (y - 1) : sieve xs (propagatePrime x ys)  
        | otherwise = y : sieve xs ys
    propagatePrime j = applyEvery (\x -> (quot x j)*(j - 1)) j

totientSum :: Int -> Int
totientSum n = sum $ take n totients
```

When computing `totientSum n` for `n` above 40000, ghci takes ages to evaluate and starts consuming tremendous amounts of memory. Compiling to an executable doesn't help. I assume that this has something to do with the way Haskell handles lazy evaluation.

I would like to know if it's possible to selectively apply strictness to improve memory consumption of the above functions so that I can compute the totient sum up to 1000000. I would also like to know if there's a better way to do this using lists, or if I should use a random-access data structure. If you know of a faster algorithm for computing the totient sum, please share a reference.

I thought that the definition of `applyEvery` might make a difference, so I tried the following other implementations, but they both seemed to consume more memory than the definition used above.

```
-- <https://www.reddit.com/2tpqip/>
applyEvery' :: (a -> a) -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
applyEvery' f n = zipWith ($) (cycle (replicate (n - 1) id ++ [f]))

applyEvery'' :: (a -> a) -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
applyEvery'' f n xs = xf ++ (\(y:ys) -> f y : applyEvery'' f n ys) xb
  where
    xf = take (n - 1) xs
    xb = drop (n - 1) xs
```

Comment: Ur numbers do not match https://oeis.org/A000010

Comment: Ah, good catch. `applyEvery` should take `(j - 1)` instead of `j`. I've updated the question.

Comment: Be sure to read the performance section of the haskell tag info page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Comment: "When computing totientSum n for n above 40000, ghci takes ages to evaluate and starts consuming tremendous amounts of memory." There is your problem, you are running code in GHCI and expecting it to be performant. This will almost never ever happen. If you want good performance, you must compile with optimizations.

Comment: Otherwise, the `applyEvery` function will be a source of inefficiency. Instead you can store a map of which things must be "applied" next. This approach along with many others is covered [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In implementing [Euler product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_product_formula):

[image: Euler product formula]

you can take advantage of the fact that you are calculating Euler Phi numbers for all the numbers in the range `[1..n]`

Doing so, you may first find all the primes in the range `[1..n]` and then *instead of finding prime divisors of each number, find all the multiples of each prime number*. Obviously, the latter can be done much more efficiently.

A possible implementation would be:

```
import Data.Int (Int64)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray, elems, accum, listArray)

primes :: Integral a => [a]
primes = 2: 3: filter pred (chain [5,11..] [7,13..])
    where
    chain (x:xs) (y:ys) = x: y: chain xs ys
    pred a = all (\i -> a `mod` i /= 0) $ takeWhile (\i -> i * i <= a) primes

euler_phi :: Int64 -> [Int64]
euler_phi n = elems $ accum (\a p -> a - a `div` p) arr inc
    where
    val = takeWhile (<= n) primes
    idx = map (\i -> takeWhile (<= n) [i,2 * i..]) val

    inc = concat $ zipWith (\i j -> ($j) <$> (,) <$> i) idx val
    arr = listArray (1, n) [1..n] :: UArray Int64 Int64

main = getLine >>= print . sum . euler_phi . read
```

then:

```
\> euler_phi 20
[1,1,2,2,4,2,6,4,6,4,10,4,12,6,8,8,16,6,18,8]
```

would be [Euler totient function for the first 20 numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function#Some_values_of_the_function); and if you *compile with `-O2` flag* you may calculate the cumulative sums with a pretty decent performance:

```bsh
$ ghc --make -O2 euler_phi.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( euler_phi.hs, euler_phi.o )
Linking euler_phi ...

$ time echo 40000 | ./euler_phi
486345716

real    0m0.091s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.006s
```